# How to take a table row's column to form input field

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, aspxgridview

I have a table of data. First column of table is button; on the button there is a onclick event. One other column is firmName I want to set txtFirm name field of form section the selected row's firm Name column.

My javaScript is as follows, but it does not work as expected

```js
function callme(e) {
  var tds = e.getElementsByTagName('td');
  document.getElementById("txtFirmaAdi").value = tds[1].innerHTML.trim();
}
```

```html
<table id="ctl03_ucOzgecmisTecrube_ctlGridSgkTecrube">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>İşyeri Sicil No</th>
      <th>İşyeri Adı</th>
      <th>Meslek Kodu</th>
      <th>Meslek</th>
      <th>Süre</th>
      <th>Baş Tar</th>
      <th>Bit Tar</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" name="ctl03$ucOzgecmisTecrube$ctlGridSgkTecrube$ctl02$btnAktar" value="Aktar" onclick="return callme(this);" id="ctl03_ucOzgecmisTecrube_ctlGridSgkTecrube_ctl02_btnAktar" class="inp"></td>
      <td>43821010110221190210174</td>
      <td>GELİŞİM TEM.İNŞ.GIDA TEL.SAN.TİC.LTD.ŞTİ.</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>240</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>31.12.2004</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The `e` you are passing to your function, is the `input` element. Of course you won't find any `td` elements _in_ that button.

Comment: How exactly is your function wrong? Is there an error?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the button to the function.

Use .closest to find the parent

Firm name in your code is in the 2nd column (according to Google Translate of İşyeri Adı) zero based - so td[1], but you have a very long number there `43821010110221190210174` which seems to match a `İşyeri Sicil No`

If I add a `<th></th>` and change to td[2] it makes more sense

```js
function callme(button) {
  const number = button.closest("tr").querySelectorAll("td")[2].textContent.trim(); 
  document.getElementById("txtFirmaAdi").value = number;
}
```

```html
<table id="ctl03_ucOzgecmisTecrube_ctlGridSgkTecrube">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>İşyeri Sicil No</th>
      <th>İşyeri Adı</th>
      <th>Meslek Kodu</th>
      <th>Meslek</th>
      <th>Süre</th>
      <th>Baş Tar</th>
      <th>Bit Tar</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" name="ctl03$ucOzgecmisTecrube$ctlGridSgkTecrube$ctl02$btnAktar" value="Aktar" onclick="return callme(this);" id="ctl03_ucOzgecmisTecrube_ctlGridSgkTecrube_ctl02_btnAktar" class="inp"></td>
      <td>43821010110221190210174</td>
      <td>GELİŞİM TEM.İNŞ.GIDA TEL.SAN.TİC.LTD.ŞTİ.</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>240</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>31.12.2004</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="text" id="txtFirmaAdi" value="" />
```